# Wordpress returning "XHR" even when access keys are used

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

I have been developing an application for woocommerce for some time and I got to the part where I need to send "POST" type requests to the "wp-json" endpoint, when I make the request I send along with the necessary information my authentication keys that I created in Woocommerce configuration area, but even with the access keys I get the "Cross-origin" (XHR) error.

I have already researched and seen in some places that I need to configure my "functions.php" file in Access-Control-Allow-Origin / Methods but when people are using my application I would not want them to have to do any extra configuration for That works.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Is this across two different domains?

Comment: yes @czerspalace